# Do not load directive for certain route(s)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to build a 'signin' page for my app that loads whenever a user is not authenticated. The navbar and footer in my app contain data which can only be loaded for authenticated users. Therefore I would like to conditionally hide the navbar and footer directives whenever my route is `/signin`.

Here is the body of my `index.html`:

```
<body ng-app="gameApp">
  <dm-navbar ng-if="!$root.notAuthenticated"></dm-navbar>
  <ng-view></ng-view>
  <dm-footer ng-if="!$root.notAuthenticated"></dm-footer>
</body>
```

...and in my `signinController` I set `$rootScope.notAuthenticated = true`

This successfully removes `gm-navbar` and `gm-footer` from the DOM. However, the controller logic associated with these directives still fires (as I see `401` errors in the console).

Answer (score 2):

Well there are a couple of ways. Are you keeping state of the logged in user in some object. Like the controller for /signin holds `$scope.userInfo`? If so, you can just do :

```
<gm-navbar ng-if="userInfo"></gm-navbar>
```

This will hide the directive if the userInfo variable is loaded with the logged in user. This way, you can abstract this approach to all pages that need to hide this, not just /signin

How you populate the user info is up to you, but let's say you're using JWT, you would send a /GET request to the server with the token, and the server would respond with user info, etc.

Comment: The problem is that `gm-navbar` and `gm-footer` are at the 'root' of my application, in `index.html`. So even if I set `notAuthenticated` to `true` in my `signinController` these directives would still load. What I may try is to set `$rootScope.notAuthenticated` to `true` in my `signinController` then throw a `ng-if="!$root.notAuthenticated"` on both `gm-navbar` and `gm-footer`.

Comment: I've added details to my original question based on progress I made thanks to your answer. It appears that the controller logic associated with the directives still fires before the `ng-if`s remove these directives from the DOM, so I'm unfortunately still seeing the `401`s which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Why not the opposite? Set notAuthenticated to be false by default, and only set it to true when you know for sure the user is logged in.